# Use Unity 3D exported project as subproject

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have 2 apps. One is exported from Unity 3D, and I want to integrate this app into my other app project tha is native. Something like a subproject or a static lib.

I press a button in my native app and show the game scene in other view controller.

Someone help me please!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible I believe, when you export a unity project you can't access individual scenes or parts from that project anymore.
The only way I see is combining the two projects and than exporting them as one.

Comment: So.. I can´t show my game scene from a native UI? I do not want to access individual parts, I want to show the scene and send a message to the game execute example "GameMenu.selectOption(3)". Is this possible?

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry I thought you meant you had an exported unity project and another unity project which you wanted to link together but you have a unity project and another program running native..
Well it still is the same problem though.. as far as I am aware you can not call to components or scripts in a exported unity project.

Comment: It's possible. Unity has native solution that you can modify AppController class to hook up with your native iOS view, or Unity view. Then you can switch between the two.

Like @dennismuys said that you cannot access individual part (i.e. scene) but you can send message to Unity app from native iOS code which scene number or task you want it to do or prepare whenever you switch the view to Unity view.